# C Linux Warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, linux, casting, warnings

I have a C linux function which has the following code:

```
void A (char *s1, char *s2)
{
...
*s2 = NULL;
...
}
```

in this function I put values into s2, and at the end put NULL.

the code:

```
*s2 = NULL
```

generates the following warning:
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

I want to fix my code, how can I do that?

thanks

Comment: Whatever you do, **do not add a cast**! The warning message would have been better if it didn't mention casts at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your system appears to have `NULL` defined as something like `(void *)0`.  That means your assignment is doing just what the warning says - making an integer from a pointer without a cast.  You don't want to put `NULL` into a `char` variable anyway - you are probably looking for:

```
*s2 = '\0';
```

Comment: this is actually nothing more than an ugly way to write `*s2 = 0;` - remember, character literals are integer constants in C, so there really is no benefit to use `'\0'` over plain `0`...

Comment: @Christoph, that sounds pretty subjective, but you're right that `0` will work just as well.

Comment: I find it important to point out to beginners that in C, there is no difference between `0` and `'\0'` except that the latter is harder to type; 'character' literals have type `int`, which confuses people with a C++ background, and the pervasive use of `'\0'` doesn't help as it suggest that there is something special about it and you *must* use it to terminate strings...

Comment: @Christoph, the same could be said for `NULL`, except that sometimes it's a `0` cast to a pointer type to cause a warning just like in the OP's question.  You can still just replace every `NULL` in a program with a `0` and have it be the same - why not use context specific hints to pick which of `0`, `'\0'`, or `NULL` to use?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the [null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), not the [NULL pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29#Null_pointer):

```
*s2 = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two similar terms:

- NULL (4 letters) → this one is a pointer.
- NUL (3 letters) → this one is a character (ASCII 0).